# How to prevent window.onbeforeunload event being triggered by button and links events

Tags: javascript, onbeforeunload

My form contains multiple buttons and hyperlinks and i want to show alert on back button of browser.
I have used below code which works fine on Chrome and Safari but not working in IE and Firefox:

```
       window.onload = function() {

            var btnClicks = document.getElementsByClassName('noPopup');
            var links = document.getElementsByTagName('a');

            for (var i = 0; i < links.length; i++) {
                links[i].onclick = setGlobal;
            }
            for (var i = 0; i < btnClicks.length; i++) {
                btnClicks[i].onclick = setGlobal;
            }
            function setGlobal() {
                window.btn_clicked = true;
                window.linkClicked = true;
            }

              window.onbeforeunload = function() {
                  if (!window.btn_clicked || !window.linkClicked) {
                      return 'Would you like to save first.';
                  }
              };

      };
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

in IE - if you don't want the `onbeforeunload` to trigger - all you need to do is to set this event to `null`, like this:

```
window.onbeforeunload = null;
```

so what you would have to do is - add a click event listener to all your buttons and links (which redirect user to a different URI) and inside that listener - set the `onbeforeunload` event listener to `null` once they are clicked (before proceeding with the normal link/button action. Otherwise - set it to function (like you have in your code).

e.g.:

```
document.getElementById('myLink').onclick = function () {
    window.onbeforeunload = null;
};
```

Comment: Since OP is using pure JS, could you please update your example to remove the jQuery part and use pure JS?

Comment: Here you overrun window.onbeforeunload, so if the user clicks mybutton that does not redirect him outside and then clicks back button he will not see the onbeforeunload happens

Comment: @ekeren Yes, if the button doesn't redirect outside - the button should not trigger the `onbeforeunload` event, hence the overrun is not required. I updated my post. Thanks

Comment: In IE 8, this does not work. IE first executes the method triggered by onbeforeunload.

Comment: @NicolasBarbulesco No. Every browser first triggers link click event and then redirects to the link url, including IE3+. Otherwise the `preventDefault` function wouldn't make sense...

Comment: @tborychowski — You say no. But I have just seen it with my eyes. And I am developing a workaround for this behaviour of IE 7 & 8. IE 9 and newer have a different (nicer) behaviour.

Answer (score 2):

Using this beforeunload will occur only on browser close neither occur on refresh of any click of anchor and also it will act as unload event by excluding return for hiding built-in popup message on before unload event

```
    function confirmExit()
    {
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: site_url + 'welcome_login/logout',
            success: function (data)
            {
            }
        });
    }
    $(window).on('mouseover', (function () {
        window.onbeforeunload = null;
    }));
    $(window).on('mouseout', (function () {
        window.onbeforeunload = confirmExit;
    }));
```

Mouse Out Occurs on Closing Browser window

Comment: URL to destroy the session & cookies. just path of that class/function

Comment: Session.Abandon and Cookies.Clear ?

Comment: @Kiquenet Yes, both

Comment: Avoid postbacks, links, F5 refresh, back button ?

Comment: *any click of anchor*. I f**king love you.